# XSL: Why I always get unreadable Spanish characters in HTML

Tags: java, xml, rest, xslt, xhtml

I plan to get an XHTML page generated by XSL and XML file, and there is an existing xsl file which focuses on English, and now I am trying to create a new one to get a Spanish HTML, but the HTML I got cannot display the Spanish characters correctly.

**CDA_es.xsl:** (The Spanish word - *Empleado guía telefónica* are always displayed as **Empleado guÃ­a telefÃ³nica** in HTML generated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:n1="urn:hl7-org:v3"
                xmlns:in="urn:lantana-com:inline-variable-data">
    <xsl:import href="CDA_en.xsl"></xsl:import>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:variable name="lang.note" select="'Empleado guía telefónica:'"></xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CDA_en.xsl**(Shown part of it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:n1="urn:hl7-org:v3"
                xmlns:in="urn:lantana-com:inline-variable-data">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"/>
    <xsl:param name="limit-external-images" select="'yes'"/>
    <!-- A vertical bar separated list of URI prefixes, such as "http://www.example.com|https://www.example.com" -->
    <xsl:param name="external-image-whitelist"/>
    <!-- string processing variables -->
    <xsl:variable name="lc" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uc" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    <!-- removes the following characters, in addition to line breaks "':;?`{}“”„‚’ -->
    <xsl:variable name="simple-sanitizer-match"><xsl:text>&#10;&#13;&#34;&#39;&#58;&#59;&#63;&#96;&#123;&#125;&#8220;&#8221;&#8222;&#8218;&#8217;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="simple-sanitizer-replace" select="'***************'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="javascript-injection-warning">WARNING: Javascript injection attempt detected in source CDA document. Terminating</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="malicious-content-warning">WARNING: Potentially malicious content found in CDA document.</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lang.note" select="'IMPORTANT:'"></xsl:variable>

    <!-- global variable title -->
    <xsl:variable name="title">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:title)  &gt;= 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:title"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:code/@displayName">
                <xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:code/@displayName"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>Clinical Document</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Main -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="n1:ClinicalDocument"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- produce browser rendered, human readable clinical document -->
    <xsl:template match="n1:ClinicalDocument">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
                <xsl:comment> Do NOT edit this HTML directly: it was generated via an XSLT transformation from a CDA Release 2 XML document. </xsl:comment>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
                </title>
                <xsl:call-template name="addCSS"/>
            </head>
            <body class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="education-text">
                                <div>
                                    <!--<strong>IMPORTANT:</strong>-->
                                    <strong><xsl:value-of select="$lang.note"></xsl:value-of></strong>
                                </div>
                                <div>Per your share settings, items highlighted in Red are marked for redaction and will
                                    not be shared; they are only shown for review purposes.
                                    Always consult your doctor regarding possible risks and side effects resulting from
                                    your sharing preferences and settings.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Code of Transformation

```
    String segmentedClinicalDocument = new String(dssResponse.getTryPolicyDocument(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Document taggedClinicalDocument = documentXmlConverter
                    .loadDocument(segmentedClinicalDocument);
    String xslUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(getCdaXSL()).toString();
    String output = xmlTransformer.transform(taggedClinicalDocument, xslUrl, Optional.<Params>empty(), Optional.<URIResolver>empty());
    TryPolicyResponse tryPolicyResponse = new TryPolicyResponse();
    tryPolicyResponse.setDocument(output.getBytes());
    return tryPolicyResponse;
```

And in the controller, the request mapping is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tryPolicyXHTML", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

In the front-end：

```
function tryPolicySuccess(response) {
      var encodedDocument = response.document;
      var decodedDocument = atob(encodedDocument);
      var viewer = $window.open('', '_blank');
      viewer.document.open().write(decodedDocument);
 }
```

I have googled the similar cases a lot, and most of them consider that the reason is the encoding, but I checked my XSL, XML files several times and pretty sure that all of them are encoded in UTF-8. I cannot find any other reasons that cause the problem of my case, anyone who have a thought about the root cause for this problem?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

Replace the default *atob(encodedDocument)* with *b64DecodedUnicode (encodedDocument)*

```
function b64DecodedUnicode(str) {
            return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function(c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }).join(''));
        }
```

Comment: How do you run the transformation, how do you look at the HTML result?  Is the HTML document loaded over HTTP and could the server perhaps send some HTTP Content-Type header with a charset parameter declaring an 8-bit encoding like Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Thanks, @MartinHonnen, It is a RESTful API, and I added the details about how the transformation works , any issue about that ?

Comment: So you use client-side Javascript to open a new browser window/tab and then you `document.write` the response to it and the browser wrongly displays the non-ASCII Spanish characters? Have you checked which encoding the browser assumes (for instance using menu "view->text encoding" in Firefox)? Are you using the approach with `atob` successful with other non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Yes, and I found that the result of decoding by atob(encodedDocument) for non-ASCII Spanish characters are unreadable. I tried with Chinese words, the result I got is still unreadable. I am pretty sure that the document is encoded in UTF-8, do you think the reason of this error could be due to the decoding ?

Comment: the browser itself can display non-ASCII characters normally

Comment: @MartinHonnen Problem was fixed by the following code: function b64DecodedUnicode(str) {
            return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function(c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }).join(''));
        }

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell there are various places in your code where conversion and encoding/decoding happens and can go wrong, for instance `output.getBytes()` with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes() suggests it is not suitable to deal with anything but the platform's default charset which might be an 8-bit charset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132596/discussion-between-w-zhou-and-martin-honnen).